# What's the purpose of xml files next to the dll?

Tags: .net, asp.net, dll

For instance, log4net.dll comes with log4net.xml. What's the use of this xml?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the "log4net.xml" file that gets added to your bin folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184102/what-is-the-log4net-xml-file-that-gets-added-to-your-bin-folder)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This file contains description of the classes, methods, etc created as xml comments in the assembly.

The [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc) says:

> The compiler generated XML file can be distributed alongside your .NET
>   assembly so that Visual Studio and other IDEs can use IntelliSense to
>   show quick information about types or members. Additionally, the XML
>   file can be run through tools like DocFX and Sandcastle to generate
>   API reference websites.

Comment: But what is the 'purpose' of them?

Comment: I think the OP wants to know when it's ok to delete and when not to. Ex. You need the PDB file to be able to debug. In another answer Will says Visual Studio relies on the xml files to display intellisense, I don't think that is true. Is there a reason to keep them around other than to use them as a manifest?

Comment: my question is same, is it okie to delete the xml?

Answer (score 32):

They contain the comments for the code in xml format. They can be used with [sandcastle](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB) to generate windows help files or MSDN-style html documents.

Comment: and Visual Studio needs them in order to display intellisense for the assembly.

Comment: @Will how would that work? I'm using a dll (sharpPDF) with Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and both files are included in the project (even though I never made any reference to the XML file). How would I get Intellisense to work properly?

Comment: @Jules: as long as they travel with each other, have the same name (xyz.dll, xyz.xml) it should be picked up.  Check your reference, you might be pointing at a dll somewhere else.

Comment: it's possible to delete xml file in release generation?

Comment: I believe it is safe to remove the XML files from release. You can prevent them being copied in the first place as well. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011434/preventing-referenced-assembly-pdb-and-xml-files-copied-to-output