# Geode Native Client - Deployment

Tags: geode

How do you deploy an application built on Geode Native Client?  I can run it on my DEV machine, but when I deploy to a different PC I get "could not load file or assembly Apache.Geode.dll.

I have all the DLLs on my DEV machine deployed in the bin directory on the deployment PC.   Do I have to do that whole mess of installing Geode Native Client on every deployment PC, or am i missing something in my Bin directory?

Comment: By the way, the second PC has Geode up running and configured as well.   I even copied the sample "put-get-remove" bin folder to the second PC and tried to run that.  I still get the same exception about dll(s) not found.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re deploying on Windows it could be the library registrations in the General Assembly Cache. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881415/system-io-filenotfoundexception-with-pivotal-gemfire-dll) could help

Comment: Yes.  I found that link and it was basically the same issue.  the build was done in debug mode, so the missing c++ libs were the debug version(s).   Thanks for the help.